# What is the borne function mentioned in this paper?

Tags: statistics

On page 16, first paragraph of [this paper](http://search.arxiv.org:8081/paper.jsp?r=1504.04296&qid=14331998030919a_nCnN_779701406&qs=program&in=q-fin), the authors introduce a function called "borne", which divides the normal distribution into n ranges of equal size, without citation. The definition is clear enough for implementation, but I couldn't find any other reference to this function. Where did the authors come up with this name and is there a more standard or more rigorous definition of it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's French](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french-english/borne/10141) for bound or limit (the authors are French) and it means whatever they define it to be ;)

I'm was not aware of this concept before and so I don't know a description or definition in English of the same.